# Как найти всех предков без внуков?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

знаю, что формулировка вопроса звучит странно, но не смог по-другому.

есть примерно такой запрос, который ищет всех elders, parents и childs.

```
SELECT `elders`.* FROM `elders` LEFT JOIN `parents` ON `elders`.`col` = `parents`.`elders_col` LEFT JOIN `childs` ON `parents`.`col` = `childs`.`parents_col`
```

т.к. юзаю yii2, то с использованием конструктора выглядит так:

```
$model = Elders::find()->joinWith('parents.childs')->asArray()->all();
```

мне же нужно найти всех elders, у которых может быть связь с parents, но у parents не может быть childs.

помогите сформулировать такой запрос.

Comment: А четвертый уровень если попросят - еще таблицу сделаете?

Comment: @u_mulder, возможно. а вы как предлагаете сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос выбирает только тех `elders`, у которых есть `parents` без `childs`

```
SELECT `elders`.*
FROM `elders`
JOIN `parents`
ON `elders`.`col` = `parents`.`elders_col`
LEFT JOIN `childs`
ON `parents`.`col` = `childs`.`parents_col`
WHERE `childs`.`id` is NULL
```